# The application does not start on the phone with these settings

Tags: java, android, android-studio

The application does not start on the phone with these settings.
After adding AdMob implementation

```
'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:17.1.2'.
```

Errors began to appear. And the application stopped compiling. Fixed pressure in the settings:

```
implementation 'com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0'
implementation 'com.android.support:support-media-compat:26.0.0'
```

But after building the application does not start on the device. What could be the problem? In addition to connecting AdMob initially did not change anything.

[image]

Comment: did you try 'Sync Project with Grade Files' ? It's the green circle icon in the upper right corner

Comment: Yes, sync. There is no result.